# How to create a resizeable box that keeps margins

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating games portal and restricted to sizing issues because of google's AdSense.
My main problem, as described below is handling games with different sizes.

Here's a (colorful) demonstration:
[image]

*Limitations*

- There most be at least 150px between the **white** box and the **red** (and **green**) box.
- The red/green box size must be 160x600 px.
- The white box should stay in the middle.

*Problems:*

- The white box (where the game is) size isn't fixed. it can be 640x480 px, 800x600 px etc...
- If the white box is too high, it could break the yellow container.
- if the white box is too wide, distance between red/green blocks could break.

*Question:*

- How to set my css to handle different sizes but to keep the margins?

Here's the basic html I work on:

```
<div class="the-rest">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="game-name">
                Title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="left">
                Left bar
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                Data comes here
                <div class="game">
                    Resizeable game comes here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                Right bar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set your div positions to absolute and the resizable position to relative. Then the div can grow and grow without influencing the other ones.

Comment: "If the white box is too high, it could break the yellow container." yes obviously it'll overflow if it's too big. is that a statement, or is it how you want to handle it? is scrollbars not a problem?